# Uncompress .Z file

Tags: gzip, unzip, compression

I have a file N225.e00.Z.zip.  I can unzip it and hvae the file N225.e00.Z, and am stuck there.  Using Python 2.6

I've been looking and tried 3 different ways to unzip this with no success.

1)

```
import zlib, gzip, os

ncomp = os.popen("uncompress -c " + zfile + ">" _ os.path.splitext(zfile)[0] )
```

this returns the file N225.e00 but it's size is 0

2)

```
import zlib, gzip, os

zfile = r"C:\N225.e00.Z
zrecover = r"C:\N225.e00

str_obj1 = open(zfile, "rb").read()
str_obj2 = zlib.compress(str_obj1)
f = open(zrecover, "wb")
f.write(str_obj2)
f.close()
```

this returns N225.e00 and it has a file size but it is smaller than the origional, and isn't really uncompressed.

the last one I tried good old gzip

3)

```
import zlib, gzip, os

zfile = r"C:\N225.e00.Z

f = gzip.open(zfile, "rb")
filecontent = f.read()
f.close()
```

I get an error IOError: Not a gzipped file.

Comment: Can you uncompress it via a bash shell?

Comment: currently it does not appear to be possible to do with a native python library (calling an external program to unZ may be your only choice). Look here `http://www.chilkatsoft.com/python-zip.asp`, it's not clear how they do it (see the bottom of the feature list)

Comment: never used a bash shell, I'm stuck on a win xp machine to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't pipe things. Just use `uncompress`:

```
os.system('uncompress {filename}'.format(filename = 'C:\\N225.e00.Z'))
```

Comment: OK, tried that as written and I get a flash on the screen but nothign happens, so I added the end of my popen to yours and it creates a empty file again.  I am forced to do this on a win xp machine.

Comment: It should create the file in your current working directory (usually `C:/Users/Username/`).

Comment: Ok, maybe this is my lack of python, but I checked my working dir using pring os.getcwd() and ran your line, at the shell I get "1", but nothing shows up in the working dir.